# Qiv slideshow state

Tags: slideshow

I use qiv to show a picture slideshow. I would like to know if I can get the current state of the slideshow? Play or pause.
Thank you for supporting

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "get the current state"? programmatically or a visual indicator?

Comment: programmatically. In fact, my goal is to remotely control the qiv slideshow. So i would like to send the current state.